# Get attribute from select option different from value

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, select-options

After a ajax call i populate a select option in this way adding a value attribute and another one called `jobDescription`:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {   
                 $('#mySelect').append($("<option></option>").attr({"value": value.id, "jobDescription": value.jobDescription}).text(value.name)); 
            });
```

when i select one of the option i need to get the `jobDescription` value. To do that I tried in this way

```
$("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("jobDescription"));
});
```

but it returns `undefined`. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Going by your original code, you need to first add `find(':selected').` first before the `.attr` to find the current selected `<option>` in `#mySelect`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').attr("jobDescription"));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="someValue" jobDescription="jobDesc1">Lorem Ipsum 1</option>
  <option value="someValue" jobDescription="jobDesc2">Lorem Ipsum 2</option>
  <option value="someValue" jobDescription="jobDesc3">Lorem Ipsum 3</option>
</select>
```